# Write a program in C that removes leading and trailing spaces from a string

Tags: c, c-strings

This is a problem from the Data Structures and Algorithms textbook by Thareja. I am trying to solve the problems to be prepared for my Data Structures class. I am compiling and running this at https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler. My program is coming to a segmentation fault and it is never entering the if statement(I cannot seem to find out why). The issue is possibly trivial and I am overlooking it but I would like another set of eyes to take a look at it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>    
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[100],ans[100];
    int i=0,j=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter string: ");
    gets(str);

    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if(str[i]==' ')
        {
            i++;
            continue;
        } 
        ans[j]=str[i];
        j++;
    }
    ans[j]='\0';
    printf("\nThe string is: ");
    puts(ans);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: First of all, [***never ever*** use the `gets` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used). Use e.g. [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Secondly, this is probably a very good time for you to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). For example, if you step through the code line by line in a debugger, you should be able to find out the error really quickly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Only in real code. In practice problem where it's guaranteed that the input is less than a number of bytes then it's safe, but then, why developing bad practice?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am new to C. I am just following what the textbook has taught me. I have walked through my code multiple times and have come here as a last resort. Please help me out.

Comment: Think how your counters are incremented ... What will happen when you hit first non-space character?

Comment: @qrdl Thanks for explaining this. I get how it works now. It was an overlook on my part.

Comment: To be frank, if the book you read told you to use `gets` then you should start looking for a more modern book that doesn't use it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like the problem is with increment operator on variable `i`.
Lets assume, the string user entered is not null and there is no leading space(s). 
      In this case, your code enters while loop successfully (coz it couldn't find a null character) and next thing it checks if is a blank space `(str[i]==' ')` , which according to assumption is not so it moves on to store the character in  in `ans[j]`. 
      At this point everything looks okay but the program moves to next line your code increments `j` but what about `i`? By not incrementing `i` you're making while loop to enter an infinite loop.
      Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you like to improve your answer by reviewing its formatting?

Comment: Ok this makes sense to me. I did not think in this context. I was assuming my test case to contain a leading space and I completely overlooked that possibility. Thanks!